# Can I set multiple window.setTimeout events in a for loop?

Tags: javascript

Here's a piece of code I copied from
http://www.schillmania.com/content/projects/javascript-animation-1/demo/
Very simple JS animation:

```
function doMove() {
  foo.style.left = parseInt(foo.style.left)+1+'px';
  setTimeout(doMove,20); 
}
```

This works fine. However if I change it like this:

```
function doMove() {
   for (var i=0; i<1000; i++) {
       setTimeout(function(){foo.style.left = parseInt(foo.style.left)+1+'px';},20*i);
   }
}
```

Consequently there's no animation at all.
As far as I know JS engine pushes those events into the queue whenever setTimeout is called. So I just don't understand why this doesn't work.

Comment: To answer the question's title, you -can- set multiple timers. You should have the code as `setTimeout("foo.style.left = parseInt(foo.style.left)+1+'px';",20*i);`.

Comment: @mizuho We stopped passing strings into setTimeout a long time ago, that has nothing to do with the problem

Comment: @NSF That use of HTMLElement.style in the code is not cross browser compatible. In the example you show, they are forced to initialize foo.style.left="1px" in script even though they have already set it in CSS. You should use a library for retrieving CSS styles, or implement correct cross browser behavior. http://robertnyman.com/2006/04/24/get-the-rendered-style-of-an-element/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a semi-colon after the for loop. Hence the loop runs for 1000 times and the setTimeout for one time.

```
// Runs for 1000 times
for (var i=0; i<1000; i++);

// Runs one time moving foo by 1px
setTimeout(function(){foo.style.left = parseInt(foo.style.left)+1+'px';},20*i);
```

Lack of proper indentation :)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a closure to preserve the value of `i` "at that time"

```
for (var i=0; i<1000; i++){
    (function(i){
        setTimeout(function(){
            foo.style.left = parseInt(foo.style.left)+1+'px';
        },20*i);
    }(i));
}
```

Comment: `i` is never used from the closure

Answer (score 0):

```
function doMove() {
  foo.style.left = parseInt(foo.style.left)+1+'px';
  setTimeout(doMove,20); 
}
```

The callback function will be executed only once by `setTimeout`, the above code works because the callback function is the function it self, so it is called recursive.

Comment: Not true, the loop is calling setTimeout 1000 times, increasing the delay each time

Answer (score 0):

```
function doMove() { for (var i=0; i<1000; i++)
setTimeout(function(){foo.style.left = parseInt(foo.style.left)+1+'px';},20*i); }
```

after for loop, there is Unnecessary semicolon;

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop line ends with a semi-colon, it's not looping. It should work if you fix that.